# Getting range of Math.random between 50–5000

Tags: java

I want to get min, max and avg of an array, from Math.random in a range of 50–5000. This is my code below but it excludes 50 every time I run it. I see that the minimum is shown 51 or sometimes 52. How do I exactly get it 50 or below 50 for min because max shows correctly. The only problem is min part.

Thanks in advance

```java
public class Main {

    private double max(double[] array) {
        double max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public double min(double[] array) {
        double min = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double array[] = new double[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            array[i] =  ((Math.random() * ((5000 - 50) + 1)) + 50);
        }

        Main main = new Main();

        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            total = total + array[i];
        }

        double average = total / array.length;


        System.out.println(main.max(array));
        System.out.println(main.min(array));
        System.out.println(average);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your need to clarify what you want. You want to exclude 50? Does your code show 50 as min or not?

Comment: You want a random number, or 50?

Comment: I want to include 50 as min as well, but min shows even higher than 50 so sometimes 51 or 52

Comment: Remove that ` + 1`.

Comment: out put  4999
52
2554.605

Comment: @forpas i did min even goes higher : array[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * ((5000 - 50) ) + 50));

Comment: You are getting random numbers, so the minimum of them is very likely to be more than 50.

Comment: yeah I know, but I thought by providing that range to Math.random you avoid that from happening, so what I can do with Math.ranom to be bounded to that range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this.  It's much easier.

```java
      Random rand = new Random();
      // generate 1000 elements between 50 inclusive and 5000 exclusive.
      double[] nums = rand.doubles(1000,50,5000).toArray();
```

or you prefer using a loop

```java
   Random rand = new Random();
   double[] nums = new double[1000]
   for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      nums[i] = rand.nextDouble(4950) + 50; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have to write this assignment on Math.random, but I tried your way just to test, even your way min passes 50

Comment: When you say it passes 50 I'm not certain what you mean.  The JavaDoc says that it will be generated.  But it is very rare considering all the possibilities.  Just like Math.random will generate 0 but it is rare.

Comment: oh god, I made such stupid mistake, you are absolutely right, your way works, I am so embarrassed I am not gonna even mention what i was missing :D

Comment: I assure you that whatever mistake you made, most of us here made it first (at one time or another).

Comment: BTW, the `Random` class also has `ints()` so you don't have to multiply and then cast to an int.

Answer (score 0):

in this segment of your code get rid of the plus one, java is inclusive on the starting number but exclusive on the end. try getting rid of the "+ 1" and make 5000 now 5001.

```
    array[i] =  ((Math.random() * ((5000 - 50) + 1)) + 50);
```

Comment: array[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * ((5001 - 50) )) + 50); it doesnt help now min even goes higher to 61 even